# gpg : encryption/decryption failed

Tags: encryption, gnupg

I try to make a gpg encryption/decryption on my server, for encryption i make this command line :

```
gpg --output test.txt.gpg --encrypt test.txt
```

and then i enter a user ID and my file is created.

But after, when i want to decrypt this file with same commande :

```
gpg --output result.txt --decrypt test.txt.gpg
```

result is :

```
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key, ID FF070B4D, created 2017-07-19
"droli mail_adress"
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

i don't understand why i can encrypt but can't decrypt after ?

```
$gpg --list-keys  
/home/ssie/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
----------------------------- 
pub   2048R/09C41BAC 2017-07-19 
uid                  droli  mail_adress 
sub   2048R/6D2F1BE9 2017-07-19

$gpg --list-secret-keys
/home/ssie/.gnupg/secring.gpg
-----------------------------
sec   2048R/09C41BAC 2017-07-19
uid                  droli  mail_adress sub
ssb   2048R/6D2F1BE9 2017-07-19
```

Edit after 2 hours :

I think to have find why : there were 2 different keys and 1 secret key for the same user. But now there is another issue : i deleted the wrong key and make the same test again.

the answer after decrypt is :

> You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for user:  "droli
>   mail_adress" 2048-bit RSA key, ID 6D2F1BE9,  created 2017-07-19 (main
>   key ID 09C41BAC)
>
> can't connect to `/home/ssie/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent': Connection refused 
>   gpg-agent[32298]: command get_passphrase failed: Operation cancelled 
>   gpg: cancelled by user gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key,  ID
>   6D2F1BE9, created 2017-07-19 "telefact " gpg: public key decryption 
>   failed: General error gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

what is this "S.gpg-agent" ? (the file /home/ssie/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent is empty in my case)

```
$ gpg-agent 
--daemon GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/gpg-1K7fOi/S.gpg-agent:18607:1; export GPG_AGENT_INFO;
```

After launching `GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/gpg-1K7fOi/S.gpg-agent:18607:1`
and `export GPG_AGENT_INFO`

there is no ask about the gpg agent.

> You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for user:  "droli
>   mail_adress" 2048-bit RSA key, ID 6D2F1BE9,  created 2017-07-19 (main
>   key ID 09C41BAC)
>
> gpg: cancelled by user 
>   gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit RSA key,  ID 6D2F1BE9, created 2017-07-19
>   "droli mail_adress" 
>   gpg: public key decryption failed: General error 
>   gpg: decryption failed: No secret key

When creating a new key i have the same issue at the end :

Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
You need a Passphrase to protect your secret key.

gpg: cancelled by user
gpg: Key generation canceled.

it's like there is a dyfonctionnement with the passphrase ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you entering a random ID, or your ID?

Comment: it is my ID ...

Comment: Could you try running `gpg --list-secret-keys`

Comment: What OS are you running on?

Comment: my OS is unix redhat

Comment: Can you try running `eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)`

Comment: $ gpg-agent --daemon
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/gpg-1K7fOi/S.gpg-agent:18607:1; export GPG_AGENT_INFO;

Comment: Can you enter those 2 commands and see if decryption works afterwards

Comment: i dont have your 2 commands jrtapsell (very thanks for your help !)

Comment: The ones output when you ran `gpg-agent --daemon`

Comment: After launching `GPG_AGENT_INFO=/tmp/gpg-1K7fOi/S.gpg-agent:18607:1`
and `export GPG_AGENT_INFO`

there is no ask about the gpg agent but same secret key issue :(

Comment: Can you try encrypting to 6D2F1BE9

Comment: that's what i did ... but same issue !

Comment: Did the encrypted with message say the right key?

Comment: Yes sur ... the key, the secret key and the message have same ID !

Answer (score 3):

The solution is :

```
chmod o+rw $(tty)
```

before using su to become that user and it works as it should.

Comment: Yep, confirmed.

Comment: On a true multi-user system you typically do not want others to be able to read your terminal.